# How do I split a wrapped numeric list into several lines?

Tags: windows, text-editing

I have some text in this format all on 1 line:

> 1v YHWH said, Let us make man in our image, after our likeness, and God created man in his own image. 2v And God formed man from the ground, and he blew into his nostrils the breath of life, and man became a living soul endowed with speech. 3v And the Lord said, It is not good for man to be alone; I will make unto him a helpmeet. 4v And the Lord caused a deep sleep to fall upon Adam, and he slept, and he took away one of his ribs, and he built flesh upon it, and formed it and brought it to Adam, and Adam awoke from his sleep, and behold a woman was standing before him. 5v And he said, This is a bone of my bones and it shall be called woman, for this has been taken from man; and Adam called her name Eve, for she was the mother of all living.

I want to look like this:

> 1v YHWH said, Let us make man in our image, after our likeness, and God created man in his own image.
>   2v And God formed man from the ground, and he blew into his nostrils the breath of life, and man became a living soul endowed with speech.
>   3v And the Lord said, It is not good for man to be alone; I will make unto him a helpmeet.
>   4v And the Lord caused a deep sleep to fall upon Adam, and he slept, and he took away one of his ribs, and he built flesh upon it, and formed it and brought it to Adam, and Adam awoke from his sleep, and behold a woman was standing before him.
>   5v And he said, This is a bone of my bones and it shall be called woman, for this has been taken from man; and Adam called her name Eve, for she was the mother of all living.

I did a regular expression replace like `Find: "(\d+)" Replace: "\n$1"`
I tried a bunch different ways like: `--wrap` around-regular expression `--down` [cursor at end]

This would get all the verses in order but it would change all the verse numbers to 1?

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Since it's windows it kind of depends on what editor you use.

Comment: Did you forget the newline before `4v`?

Answer (score 8):

If you install [Notepad++](http://notepad-plus-plus.org/), you can use regular expressions in its *Replace with* function. Your attempt is almost correct.

- Find what: `(\d+)v`
- Replace with: `\n\1v`

Note that I used `\1` instead of `$1`.

[image]

Comment: I get more respect for Notepad++ every day

Comment: Scintilla Text Editor handles RegExp too.

Comment: yeah I've done similar split operations with N++, FTW!

Answer (score 3):

If you like to work from the command line, using [sed](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/sed.htm), this is simply:

```
C:\> sed -i 's/\([0-9]\+\)v/\n\1/g' path\to\yourfile.txt
```

Comment: I'll add my upvote if you edit your question to include how to install sed for windows.

Comment: Met you halfway, by including a link for sed for Windows. Personally, I use Cygwin, but that seems like overkill (and certainly no easier than installing NPP.)