# Can't convert text as shown in Notepad++

Tags: notepad++

I have a book – all on one line – joined like this example in Notepad++:

```
<In the beginning God created the heaven and the earth.><And the earth was without form, and void and darkness [was] upon the face of the deep. And the Spirit of God moved upon the face of the waters.><And God said, Let there be light and there was light.><And God saw the light, that [it was] good and God divided the light from the darkness.>
```

Applying these find/replace rules I tried to get each line on its own, like below, but it did not convert.

1. Find: `(\d+)`
2. Replace `\n$1`
3. Wrap around checked
4. Search Mode: Regular expression
5. Direction: Down
6. No Transparency

Any suggestion?

```
<In the beginning God created the heaven and the earth.>
<And the earth was without form, and void and darkness [was] upon the face of the deep. And the Spirit of God moved upon the face of the waters.>
<And God said, Let there be light and there was light.>
<And God saw the light, that [it was] good and God divided the light from the darkness.>
```

Comment: Please learn how to format posts and use the preview window (that's conveniently placed below the editor).

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that you've simply used the rule that was suggested to you [in a previous question of yours](https://superuser.com/questions/355201/how-do-i-split-a-wrapped-numeric-list-into-several-lines) without adapting it to your new text. You're searching for digits (`\d`) as line delimiters – but in your book, there aren't any digits.

Your text lines are delimited by `<` at the beginning. So, if you wanted to use regular expressions, you'd need to search for these instead of digits:

- Find: `(<)`
- Replace: `\n\1`

You could also do the following:

- Find `><`
- Replace: `\n`

Here, you wouldn't need regular expressions at all, which should be a little faster when replacing lots of text (which I'm assuming there is in your book).

<sub>Also note that the `(<)` expression will apply to any occurrence of a `<`, which would break the formatting if there were any `<` interspersed with the text. The `><` replacement is safer in that regard since it's very unlikely for this combination to occur.</sub>

Comment: +1 for the last line of your answer.  No Regex needed at all for this simple of a replacement.